# Passing Integer in url for REST with Hazelcast

Tags: rest, hazelcast

I want to use the REST API with curl in order to get key/value pairs from my Hazelcast map. According to the Documentation it should be like this:

```
 curl -X GET http://10.20.17.3:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/mapName/1
```

This should return the following:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 3
one
```

This works for String IDs but not for Integer IDs. If I change the key type of the map to Integer, the query

```
curl -X GET http://10.20.17.3:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/mapName/1
```

returns

```
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Content-Length: 0
```

My question is: is it possible (and if yes, how) to store a key/value pair with a key type of Integer in a map and get it via REST URL?

Comment: do you mean an int or Integer?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean Integer. I edited it.

Comment: do you see the map size in the command prompt interface to hazelcast?  Have you tested for the map size with a sample Java API call?

Comment: are you updating the map through java or REST call?

Comment: I am also assuming that you are using different map names - i.e. you're not using mapName as the name of the two maps with String and Integer keys?

Comment: I update the map via Java. Via REST I only want to get the content of the map. My map is named "customers" and this is my REST call.
`curl -X GET http://10.0.1.164:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/customers/165`

If this is a <String, String> map, everything works. But if I declare it as a <Integer, String> map (e.g. for an id), the REST call returns content of length 0.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you mistyped and meant an Integer and not an int, you should not be able to use an int as a key for a regular java hashmap (as well as the hazelcast implementation).  In short, you cannot use a primitive (e.g. int) - you need to use the wrapper implementation i.e. Integer.  There are other libraries (e.g. trove) where you can use primitives in your hashmap (they are not the standard JDK hashmap implementations).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But you guessed right, i mean a <Integer, String> map.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast REST Client supports only keys of type String